# lvalue error while incrementing an int value

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
  int a =1;
  cout<<++++a;  //Prints 3
  cout<<a++++; //Gives lvalue error
  cout<<++a++; //Gives lvalue error
}
```

The above code gives lvalue error when I am trying to increment an int value. Please explain why this error is coming for certain cases and not in another case

Comment: After the first `++` it is not an lvalue anymore.

Comment: `a++` is an rvalue.

Comment: Well duh, the operator is `<<----`, not `<<++++`

Comment: @HongOoi Would you like to rephrase that? You know ... https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of trouble, and some typing, by writing `a+=2;` No need to wear out the `+` key.

Answer (score 2):

This is an lvalue

```
int a=1;
```

This is not an lvalue `a++`, it is an rvalue, the value of `a` before incrementing. Afterwards `a` gets incremented as a side effect.

The prefix `++a` increments `a`, it is the lvalue `a`, after incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

in first case ++++a compiler firstly adding the value in a and then showing the output.
in other cases after showing the output on screen compiler cannot add the value in variable at run time for this purpose you have to use loops

Answer (score 1):

`++a` results in an lvalue while `a++` results in rvalue. Operand of pre and post increment operator should be an lvalue. Therefore, `++++a` will work as `++a` will give an lvalue. For `a++++` (will be parsed as `(a++)++`) and `++a++` (will be parsed as) `++(a++)`,  `a++` will give an rvalue and increment operator can't be applied on an rvalue (.

Answer (score 0):

the first case is `++(++a)`, now `++a` increments a by 1 and returns the new value, it's really like `a+=1;++a` so it works.

The second case `(a++)++` increments a but returns the old value so it evaluates to `3++` and 3++ is not valid at all, for the same reason the third case doesn't work.